# Powerapps - toggles in a gallery

Tags: image-gallery, toggleswitch

I have a gallery on power apps and each row is a different questions, to answer "yes, no" with a toggle. I am trying to have a submit button on the bottom of my page to send this gallery info to my share point, but I only want this button to appear if all the toggles were shifted. How do I enter all the toggles info in this button and not just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

On the visible property on your button I would wrap your if Statement with the ForAll function.
This loops through all of the records of the gallery.

Not sure if this will work but worth a try.